# How set height and width gridview element in my example

Tags: android, gridview

I made application as [here](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gridview-example/):

All is ok but I have one question.
How can I set height of element in gridview in this example ? I try-ied change height in `RelativeLayout` in `gridview_row.xml`

```
android:layout_height="250dp"
```

but height no change.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/286389/how-to-set-gridview-row-height) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

put them into another layout and try

```
 <RelativeLayout    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <ImageView></ImageView>
        <TextView></TextView> 
     </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes.Now is good.You are super:) Could you explain why it help solve my problem, because not understand.

Comment: Accept his answer first if it is useful for you. :)